# How to verify email address

Tags: spring-mvc, email

How to verify email addresses after the user sign's up with a web application and when he opens up the confirmation sent email , how to pass on the unique link to it which will redirect the user to the registration success page. I want to create my application in Spring MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below steps to implement the same.

Step 1 : Create one encrypted URL and send it to User by email.

Step 2 : Click link from the mail which will hit on one controller method and then decrypt the URL using reverse login which you used for encryption.

Step 3 : Update the status like confirmed to true in database.

NOTE : For encryption and decryption you can use below packages classes.

```
import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
```